# Making TeXLive Bera Font Accessible on MacOS/R/etc

Tags: fonts, texlive, r

I used to be able to create R graphs with texlive's bera .pfb font on macos.  Alas, somewhere along the line, it stopped working.  (I am asking in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089029/using-texlive-fonts-in-r-plots-on-macos about R.)  I also liked to use Bera elsewhere.

has someone figured out how to make the Bera .pfb font available to other macos apps (incl but not only R)?

PS: it's not far off topic to have a few fonts that work seamlessly inside and outside TeX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/bera/README) file, the true type versions of the Bera fonts (the original Bitstream Vera fonts, as Ulrike Fischer already pointed out) are part of the GNOME project:

> "Bera" is a set of three PostScript Type1 font families: Bera Serif (a
> slab-serif Roman), Bera Sans (a Frutiger descendant), and Bera Mono
> (monospaced/typewriter).  The fonts were originally designed by
> Bitstream, Inc in TrueType format under the name "Bitstream Vera".
> These fonts are available from
> http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/ttf-bitstream-vera/1.10/.

You can download them here:

http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/ttf-bitstream-vera/1.10/ttf-bitstream-vera-1.10.zip

Unzip and install as usual.

Or, if you are have [homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed, you can tap into the fonts repository with:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-fonts
```

and then simply call:

```
brew install --cask font-bitstream-vera
```

Comment: addendum: one needs to run ` brew tap homebrew/cask-fonts` once.

Comment: @ivoWelch right! will add that to the answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to install for macos in general is to use

https://www.fontconverter.org/

and convert the pfb font files to otf font files.  double-clicking on the otf files installs them in the mac os fontbook.

Comment: bera is a version of Bitstream Vera.